# Java: Cash Register

Tags: java

I am constructing a cash register app for Christmas trees. I want to be able to have multiple transactions so I can track the number of trees going on. The problem is I can do one transaction, then it ends. I have considered a while loop, but maybe I am doing it wrong because it creates an infinite loop. What can I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PosTester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        POS register = new POS();
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done)
        System.out.println("Please enter price of tree: ");
        double purchase = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Is order complete? Type: Y/N");
        String choice = in.next();


        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))

        {
            System.out.println("Your total is: " + purchase);
            System.out.println("<--------------------------->");
            System.out.println("Please enter payment amount: ");
            double payment = in.nextDouble();
            double change = payment - purchase;
            System.out.println("Your change is: $ " + change);
            int treeCount = 10; //lot contains 10 trees
            treeCount--; // remove tree from inventory

            if (treeCount == 5)
            {
                System.out.println("You're down to 5 Christmas Trees" );
            }
        }

        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            System.out.println("Please add another item");
            System.out.println("Enter price of the next tree: ");
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program will indefinitely print `Please enter price of tree:`.

You realize that `while` without curly braces only applies to the next line?

```
while (!done)
    // do something
// do something else
```

The above would only execute `do something` in an infinite loop. You really want curly braces around whatever you want to loop:

```
while (!done) {
    // do something
    // set done to true at some point, or break from the loop
}
```

A few tips:

- Indenting your code properly helps in *seeing* the issue. Most IDEs should auto-format the code for you, and you would have noticed that the `System.out.println` after your `while` was indented differently than the rest.
- If you learn how to use a debugger, the error would have become really obvious, because you would have never stepped outside the line after `while`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I overlooked the brackets. That stops the infinite loop; but, for some reason, the tree count doesn't seem to work. I am not very familiar with the debugger, and I know that is something I will have to learn. Do you know what I missed with the tree count?

Comment: Your `treeCount` is always initialized with 10, in every loop. If you ever want it to become lower, you need to initialize it somewhere outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'm pretty new at this, so it's easy for my eyes to cross looking at this code.

Comment: One other question if someone doesn't mind to help. Would it be appropriate to set up another class and create methods to calculate total sales?

Comment: That would probably make sense, if you already have a POS class to encapsulate specific behavior! It's always good to put the model logic away from the user interaction.  Since you're new to Stack Overflow, note that you can accept an answer if it solved your problem, by clicking the green checkmark next to it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I get a little confused about classes. Would I need to create all the variables over in the other class instead of the main class? What about the loops and if statements? Can they go in the separate class too?

Comment: No they can't. You'd have your main control flow in the `PosTester` class. Say you want make a class `Register` where you calculate your sales, then you create a reference to the Register with `Register reg = new Register()` in your main class, and when you make a sale, you can say, `reg.put(5)` to put $5 into the register, or `reg.take(10)` to take $10 out of it. The Register would be responsible so that it can never contain less than $0. Just an example. You might want to read a few more tutorials and examples about object-oriented Java though.

Comment: Thanks I will do that. I will mark this as answered. I appreciate the assistance.